# Can't play audio in Bluetooth headphones

Tags: audio, kde, bluetooth, plasma

I have a pair of Bluetooth headphones that I would like to use as a playback device. The first time I turned my headphones on and entered "Bluetooth pairing" mode, I was able to see them in the list of available devices and thus connect to them. After the connection was established, the headphones were correctly selected as the default output device.

However, something weird happens when I turn my headphones off and turn them back on. In particular, I am able to connect to them via Bluetooth but I'm unable to select them as the output device - they don't even show up in the Audio settings.
The only way to make them work again is to:

1. Turn the headphones off
2. Delete them from the list of known Bluetooth devices
3. Turn them back on and enter Bluetooth pairing mode
4. Connect to them

Does anybody have a clue of why this happens and how could I solve the problem?

Here are some useful info about my setup:

- OS: KDE Neon 5.22
- KDE Plasma version: 5.22.1
- Headphones model: Panasonic RB-HF420B

---

**EDIT**: The problem occurs only when my laptop *automatically* connects to the headphones via Bluetooth. If I manually connect to the headphones, then they are correctly recognized as an output device.

Comment: Assuming you are also using `pulseaudio`, I would try running `pavucontrol` and see what's default.

Comment: @Bib The default output device in `pavucontrol` is "Speakers". The other option is "Headphones (unplugged)", which doesn't solve the problem. In fact, if I select "Headphones (unplugged)", the audio doesn't come out neither from my laptop's speakers nor from the headphones

Comment: You are running `pavcontrol` when the BT headphones are paired, switched on and connected?

Comment: Exactly. By the way, I've edited my question with an important note (didn't realize that before)